# White dots in glass cup's reflection

Tags: reflection

When I make glass cup object, I notice there is alot of white dots on my glass cup's reflection like this (For your info, this is in render view mode) [image]

Since then, I try this tips https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/7-ways-get-rid-fireflies, start by set clamp direct and indirect to 50 and set seed to 1, set bounces : max = 32, diffuse = 4, glossy = 32, transmission = 32, set glossy filter by 0.5 to set up this nodes. [image]

How to get rid of this white dots?
Here is the blend file
https://pasteall.org/blend/a0e8344abc3d466d85e0f289b1cfd71c

Comment: I'm not sure you can avoid that if you've already tried all the recommendation for fireflies, the sampling is high (1000), the more you'll wait (while Blender is calculating) the less you'll see these fireflies, see: https://zupimages.net/up/22/16/8cb4.jpg

Comment: @moonboots is that object of mine? cause it has many light on its reflection

Comment: it's yours................

Comment: i wonder how to make object's shade smooth unlike in my picture. Is it because the light or something?

Comment: as we can see at the top left of your 3D view, you are just at the beginning of the calculation (Path Tracing Sample 5/1000), so there are still fireflies, you need to wait until it reaches a higher sampling to see the fireflies disappear. As for the the shade smooth of your picture, could you please highlight what you're refering to?

Comment: Oh sorry for confusing you, what i mean is "shadow" not " shade", i want to  know how i can make my object's shadow into one single smooth shadow, not just like many of black dots like in my picture and the one picture you give me

Comment: do you mean make the shadow more transparent? If I'm not wrong I think there's a problem with glass shadows in both Eevee and Cycles (although caustics should be soon fixed if I remember correctly), but there are tricks to have something more transparent if it interests you: https://blenderartists.org/t/glass-surfaces-are-treated-as-opaque-by-shadow-rays/702554

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135710/discussion-between-earvin-williams-and-moonboots).